# Cassandra migrates value from text to list of text

Tags: list, text, cassandra

I try to update my table in Cassandra database. Right now I have table which looks like

```
foo(id, email) - email text type
```

I want to update the table to something like

```
foo(id, emails) - emails list of text type
```

I added new column

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD emails set <text>;
```

but I don't know how to migrate value from email column to emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very familiar with your domain, however you have to tell Cassandra how to create the new list of emails. Take a look at [COPY](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) if you don't have too many records. You can

1. Add a new column
2. Use copy to export your existing data using `COPY TO`
3. Apply your transformations on the exported data
4. Use `COPY FROM` to upload your new data.

If you have to do this update in real time while your table is growing, this solution won't work.

Comment: Wow. It works but it is really painful. I thought that it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra don't have a native solution to do such operation.

Maybe you can create a simple migration program with your favorite programming language and follow these steps :

- Create the new column in cassandra (with `ALTER` command).
- Execute the migration program.
- Delete the old column in cassandra.

The program it self will take all record from cassandra one by one an apply the transformation.